# Create a netmodule library using many dlls

Tags: c#, c++, dll, csc, netmodules

I have a problem generating a netmodule archive, I have these files:

- class1.cs
- library1.dll
- library2.dll
- library3.dll

`class1.cs` uses `library1.dll` and `library2.dll` uses `library2.dll` and `library3.dll`, I try using this command:

```
C:\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC>csc /target:module "D:\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\Class1.cs" /reference:"C:\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\library1.dll";"D:\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\library2.dll";"C:\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\library3.dll"
```

But, only obtain a file containing class1 and library1, i need to compile 4 files in one netmodule, but i try many commands and nothing work.

pd: i use Visual Studio 2010, thanks for any help

Comment: This is  about the C# tool, csc. Why have you added a C++ tag?

Comment: because the netmodule its for use in a c++ proyect. The plan is use these librarys in a c++ application

Answer (score 0):

You must use `-reference` (or `-r`) parameter for each file separately. For a large number of parameters, it is reasonable to use a [response file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/response-file-compiler-option).